# find() returns vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, breakpoints, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a vector of floats which include the following:

```
48.2701
18.868
42.9535
7
39.2046
5.09902
29
```

I have a piece code that finds the smallest number in the vector and returns the index:

```
int indexofsmallest = 2;
smallest = *min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end());
int pos = find(distances.begin(), distances.end(), smallest) - distances.begin();
indexofsmallest = pos;

cout << "||" << smallest << "||" << endl;
cout << "index of smallest is:" << indexofsmallest + 1 << endl;
```

however when I run, it throws a vector subscript out of range breakpoint

what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Smeeheey it's the std::min_element

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Smeeheey min_element is part of <algorithm>

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/480d3a7d1a533fed)

Comment: Sorry, retracting

Comment: find returns an iterator not a subscript

Comment: Then I don't understand, why are you dereferencing returned iterator from min_element, try to find that iterator again and counting the distance. All with floating point numbers, where equality is not guaranteed.

Comment: @KIIV I have used iterator, and it doesnt throw an out_of_range exception it returns the wrong index

Comment: Please consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is types of the elements of the vector and `smallest`?

Comment: `min_element` returns an iterator. why are you looking for the element *again*?

Comment: @belkipAndroidness my point is you can't test floating point numbers for equality. It might return  'distances.end()' as value for "not found" from that find

Comment: @WhozCraig it didn't return an iterator, it returned the smallest number in the vector

Comment: @belkipAndroidness that's because you're *dereferencing* the thing. Just use `std::min_element`, not `*std::min_element`

Comment: @WhozCraig then it gives me an error:  no suitable conversion function from "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<float>>>" to "float" exists

Comment: [See example here](http://ideone.com/QMG3WW).

Comment: @KIIV I think you can test in this case, but logic is convoluted.

Comment: Do you use `indexofsmallest + 1` with vector?

Comment: @Slava no i just use that to print to the screen

Comment: @belkipAndroidness -  Why all of that code to find the index?  `auto iter = std::min_element(...); auto index = std::distance(distances.begin(), iter);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply find the index of smallest element using:

```
int smallestInd = min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end()) - distances.begin();
```

**EDIT**

This is the code I have in my editor

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    vector<double> distances = { 48.2701, 18.868, 42.9535, 7, 39.2046, 5.09902, 29 };
    cout << min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end()) - distances.begin() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it returns 34 as the index

Comment: And what is the size of your vector `distances`?

Comment: it has a size of 7 doubles

Comment: Can you edit your post and post your complete code? And not just the part where you're calculating the smallest index?

Comment: thats all the code i have

Comment: And where have you initialized the vector `distances`?

Comment: oh sorry std::vector<double> distances = { 
        48.2701,
        18.868,
        42.9535,
        7,
        39.2046,
        5.09902,
        29, };